# Стили строчек при условии

Tags: cgridview, php, yii, css

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться! 
Мне нужно вывести список заказов: там, где заявка находится в статусе "В обработке", надо выделить строку другим цветом.

Вот код:

```
  <?php
     $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'data-form-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
            'id' => array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'sortable' => 'true',
            ),
            'name',
            'tel',
            'sait',
            'date' => array(
            'name' => 'date',
            'value' => 'date("j.m.Y H:i", $data->date),
            ),
            'status' =>array(
            'name' => 'status',
            'value' => '($data->status == 0)?"В обработке":"Выполнено"',
            'filter'=> array(0 => 'В обработке', 1 => 'Выполнено'),
            ),
            array(
                'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            ),
        ),
    )); 
    ?>
```

Сделал с помощью jquery, но фон мигает постоянно. Хотелось бы решить это с помощью php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

читай вот [тут](http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=9127)